# Why Autofac 4.6.2 added bunch of assemblies?

Tags: nuget, autofac

After updating Autofac package to latest version (4.6.2) via NuGet I noticed that bunch of references was added to my solution.

```
"Microsoft.CSharp",
"System",
"System.Core",
"System.Data",
"System.Drawing",
"System.IO.Compression.FileSystem",
"System.Numerics",
"System.Runtime.Serialization",
"System.Xml",
"System.Xml.Linq"
```

This is also reproducible with empty project and only with 4.6.2.

Is there any reasons for referencing all this assemblies?

Comment: I think this is one of those "you'd have to ask them" questions.

Comment: That's because the `Autofac.nuspec` file in the Nuget package contains a `frameworkAssemblies` element with that exact list of assemblies.

Comment: can't find Autofac.nuspec on git repo